# Add integer to a year in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataset

```
    id   date        y 
    8  2017-03-03    2
    7  2012-02-01    8
```

I want to add the number y to the date. and y is a number of year :

```
    id   date         
    8  2019-03-03    
    7  2020-02-01
```

I tried with this date :

```
tmp <- as.POSIXlt(date)
tmp$year <- tmp$year + y 
date <- format(tmp)
But it's not at all the good value. 

Thank you,
```

Comment: `library(lubridate); df$date +  years(df$y)`

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't walk to. I have a big value for the year.

Comment: It works for your given example. If you have different example then the one showed please edit your question with the new example so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes it's ok, many thanks !